# Which versions of glibc do different versions of RedHat ship with?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Can anyone tell me (or point me in the direction of an online resource which outlines) which versions of glibc ship with which versions of RedHat?

[This RedHat document](http://www.redhat.com/rhel/compare/) indicates versions of GCC but doesn't mention glibc...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com) typically has a pretty good run down of what each distro has.

[Red Hat's run down](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat)

Answer (score 9):

Edit: The RedHat documentation used to list the version of the libraries they included. They have since removed that information.

This data is from [distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat). Sorry for the sideways scroll and long ASCII text. StackOverflow doesn't support Markdown Tables.

```
| Package       | RHEL-8.4  | RHEL-7.9  | RHEL-6.9  | RHEL-5.11 | RHEL-4.8  | RHEL-3.9  | RHEL-2.1  | 9         | 8.0       | 7.3       | 7.2       | 7.1       | 7.0       | 6.2   | 6.1       | 6.0       | 5.2       | 5.1       | 5.0       | 4.2       |
|               |           |           |           |           |           |           |           | shrike    | psyche    | valhalla  | enigma    | seawolf   | guiness   | zoot  | cartman   | hedwig    | apollo    | manhattan | hurricane | biltmore  |
| glibc (2.34)  | 2.28      | 2.17      | 2.12      | 2.5       | 2.3.4     | 2.3.2     | 2.2.4     | 2.3.2     | 2.2.93    | 2.2.5     | 2.2.4     | 2.2.2     | 2.1.92    | 2.1.3 | 2.1.2     | 2.1.1     | 2.0.7     | 2.0.7     | 2.0.5c    | --        |
```

It used to be available from RedHat documentation:
[RHEL 6](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/libraries.html#lib.version)
[RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Developer_Guide/libraries.html#lib.version)

Comment: The documentation seems to no longer include the glibc version. That's why it's always a good idea to include the info in the answer as well.

Comment: Any idea why RHEL5 and prior are using a higher versions than the later releases?